# Concatenation of Solr fq queries

Tags: solr

I have what seems at first blush to be a simple problem, but I can't get meaningful Solr results from a two part query.

I want to return all records which either have no roles at all, or a specific role.

Entering role:admin brings me back all the records with a a role:admin tag, -role:* bring me back all records with no roles assigned at all, but role:admin OR -role:*  brings back nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `role:admin OR (*:* -role:[* TO *])`

Comment: Thanks - It also works with just `role:admin OR (*:* -role:*)`